# Building DC to DC converter using a inductor

Tags: resistors, dc-dc-converter, inductor

Can I build a DC to DC converter like this?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkOwAL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When the switch is moved due to the low resistance path it will take a lot of time for the LR circuit to run out of power and we will have some voltage Vout for quite some time.

This obviously works for loads with high impedance (MOSFET, JFET or high value resistors) but I am worried for capacitive parasitics which may cause the system to behave differently.

Comment: Can you edit what you really want to ask with the question. Just asking "can I build this" may not get your actual problem answered.

Comment: It will work better if you short Rch and replace R2 with a capacitor.

Comment: withthe right parts, You can buiild it,  what result are you expecting?

Comment: _"This obviously works for loads with high impedance"_ Please show with a simulation.

Comment: @ThePhoton if I replace R2 with a capacitor we will have damped oscillation,critical oscillation or exponential damping'

Comment: @Jasen I am expecting a DC to DC voltage regulator .The output voltage will slowly decay over time.

Comment: @JunSeo-He, Choose a capacitor value such that the LC resonance is well below (a couple of decades is not uncommon) your switching frequency, then choose a control scheme (controlling the switch duty cycle) to avoid ringing related to the LC resonance.

Comment: with R2 You'll get a small, negative, Vout that decays exponentially towards zero while the switch it to the right while it's to the left you get zero volts.